# Spring Cloud turbine - No data returned from /turbine.stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, turbine

My techstack comprises of the following

- Eureka Discovery server
- Zuul Gateway
- Spring Config server
- Hystrix Dashboard
- My core services that has Hystrix stream enabled.

Hystrix dashboard is working fine as I am able to stream using the hystrics.stream exposed out of my services.

However, whenever I try to add turbine to this stack, the /turbine.stream only returns `data: {"type":"Ping"}` repeatedly on the browser and as a result Hystrix dashboard shows `Unable to connect to Command Metric Stream`

Can someone please assist me to find out where I am going wrong?

Here are my key configurations for turbine. The TurbineAppliation class is just a springboot app with @EnableTurbineStream so not listing it down below.

pom dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

bootstrap.yml: (Please ignore eureka specific config if it does not matter as I have not tuned them myself). The config server and eureka settings are same for all the other components which are working just fine.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Turbine
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: ConfigServer

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
#    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    preferIpAddress: true
    ipAddress: 127.0.0.1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/discovery/eureka/ ---discovery is my eureka context root required for my app
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 7980

info:
  component: Turbine App

turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: MY-SERVICE
  appConfig: MY-SERVICE
  clusterNameExpression: new String('default')
  InstanceMonitor:
    eventStream:
      skipLineLogic:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: You have turbine stream which reads from rabbit mq, do you have hystrix stream (ie to rabbit) or just HTTP?

Comment: yes my hysterix stream is also using rabbit and it works just fine

Comment: @spencergibb - do you have any ideas about what is going wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/810 There will be a Camden.SR6 with a fix hopefully next week.

Comment: ok got it, will wait for the fix

Comment: Camden.SR6 is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am dealing with the same problem using Camden.SR6.

After adding following in Turbine Service pom.xml, I was able to use turbine stream in hystrix dashboard:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also I added :  spring.rabbitmq.address=rabbit-mq-server:5672 to bootstrap.properties file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of Spring Cloud Camden SR5 the rabbitMQ queue renamed from `springCloudHystrixStream` to `turbineStreamInput`.
As a workaround you can specify the previous version of `spring-cloud-stream`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I can certainly try that, but how does the turbine stream work in this new version that I am using?

Comment: I don't know the details, it is a bug. The issue I noticed was that turbine was listening to turbineStreamInput but hystrix was sending to springCloudHystrixStream.

Comment: Thanks, we will try it out and update whenever I get some time. I moved on to other things as I could not get much info on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use for *turbine* app in your *pom*

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.M1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```